# Rownumber() unsopported in reports?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, row-number

I have the following query (This is returned by tablevalued function)

```
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ClientHId)  AS RowNumber,
ClientHId,
FirstName,
LastName,
FROM Client
```

Then I populate my dataset in SSRS like this:

`select RowNumber,ClientHId,FirstName,LastName from fuctionClient`

So far so good. Now, I am trying to use RowNumber column for sorting or displaying. If I try to sort, SSRS errors out says: `"unsopported datatype exception"` if I just try to show it in tablix it displays `#error` instead of rownumber. Visual Studio intellisense says that only integer, string, char... are supported. but Row_Number function returns integer! I was even trying to do `cast as integer` on rownumber but still does not help. Have anyone experienced the same problem? ClinetHid - HierarchyId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dreaded "Could not reproduce."

I just created a sample report with a query almost identical to yours, including creating a table-valued UDF and then calling that from the report. I then ordered the detail group by the RowNumber field without any problems. I made sure that I called the RowNumber field by the same name that you show above.

How do you declare the return datatype for that field in the UDF?

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[JamieTestFunction]
(
)
RETURNS 
@Requests TABLE 
(
    -- Make sure your type below is correct:
    [RowNumber] int, 
    [ClientID] int,
    [ClientName] NVARCHAR(200)
)
AS
BEGIN
INSERT @Requests
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ClientID)  AS RowNumber,
    ClientID,
    ClientName
    FROM clients

    RETURN;
END
```

(Also, make sure that wherever you are specifying the RowNumber to use the Field!RowNumber.Value, not the built in RowNumber() function in SSRS, which may give different results. I doubt this is your problem though.)

Comment: Yeah, I use Field!RowNumber.Value...I think, maybe the problem is that ClientId type is hierarchyId. Can you please check with hierarchyid?

Comment: Return datatype is RETURNS TABLE btw.

Comment: I expect you are right, that the HierarchyID is the problem, nothing to do with RowNumber(). Just comment out the ClientHid to test.  I don't have a table with a HierarchyID handy: seems like you can test faster than I can.

Comment: I've just changed hierarchyid to integer datatype for testing. the same problem exist. I will update my question with full code in a minute.

Comment: Please check the datatypes of the individual fields in your UDF. See my edited answer.